# How to capture the value of an information via HTML as input with Jsoup?

Tags: java, jsoup

I have a doubt, I need to capture a value that is in the HTML input using jsoup.

For example:

```
<input type = "text" id = "national" value = "3.26" style = "width: 2.3em;">
```

I need to capture only the value "3.26"

I tried using the command: `Element  mdolar = document.getElementById ("national");`

but does not display any information.
What am I doing wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following test extracts the value from an `input` element with `id=national`.

This test passes using the HTML supplied in your question.

```
@Test
public void parseInputValueFromHtml() {
    String html = "<input type = \"text\" id = \"national\" value = \"3.26\" style = \"width: 2.3em;\">";

    Document document = Jsoup.parse(html);

    Element mdolar = document.getElementById("national");
    Assert.assertEquals("3.26", mdolar.attr("value"));

    // you can also find this element by type:
    Elements mdolars = document.select("input[id=national]");
    Assert.assertEquals(1, mdolars.size());
    Assert.assertEquals("3.26", mdolars.first().attr("value"));
}
```

Comment: Hello Glytching.
Thank you for your answer !!!
Sorry, I forgot to comment that the value of "3.26" is a variable, in fact the amount I'm trying to capture is a dollar quote, so it's a variable value.

Comment: The above code will extract the `value` attribute of the `input` with `id=national` regardless of what the value of that attribute is i.e. the code doesn't care whether the value is variable or not.